# Rethrow error with Err.Raise

Tags: excel, vba, exception

**Info:** Thanks to [Gary McGill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98422/gary-mcgill) I could improve the source code of my question.

In my current project I have got a sub which handles all errors. The following should happen:

1. Start Sub
2. Send email
3. Show default Debug-Error window (which points to the original error line when clicking "Debug")

The main point here is to find out in **which line** the error occured.

```
Private Sub Foo()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    a = 7 / 0

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandling:
        errorNumber = Err.Number
        errorSource = Err.Source
        errorDescription = Err.Description
        errorHelpFile = Err.HelpFile
        errorHelpContext = Err.HelpContext
    On Error GoTo 0
    Call HandleError(errorNumber, errorSource, errorDescription, errorHelpFile, errorHelpContext)
End Sub

Public Sub HandleError(errorNumber As Integer, errorSource As String, errorDescription As String, errorHelpFile As String, errorHelpContext As String)
    Call SendMail(subject, body, mail)
    Err.Raise errorNumber, errorSource, errorDescription, errorHelpFile, errorHelpContext
End Sub
```

But if I do it that way, the newly created error window simply points to the `Err.Raise` line, not the actual line in which the error occured. Numbering the lines with an addon is no solution since my companies restrictions do not allow addons.

Are there any other possible solutions?

**Edit**

So instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvXBQ.jpg), the line `a = 7 / 0` should be highlighted

**Edit 2**

Sadly, this does not work:

```
Private Sub Foo()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    a = 7 / 0

    Exit Sub
    ErrorHandling:
        ...
        Call HandleError(...)
        GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with the code as (originally) posted:

1. The `On Error Goto 0` in `HandleError` will clear the values of `Err.Number` etc. All the `On Error` variants effectively do an `Err.Clear`. You could try saving those values at the start of the function for later use.
2. It looks like your call to `HandleError` will raise an error, which in turn will go un-handled, and drop through to your `ErrorHandling` error handler again, which will just loop? So actually, you might need to catch the various error values in the error handler, then disable the error handler, and then pass them to the `HandleError` function as parameters. Maybe something like this:

.

```
Public Sub Foo()
    On Error Goto ErrorHandling
    number = 7/0
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandling:
    errorNumber = Err.Number
    errorSource = Err.Source
    errorDescription = Err.Description
    errorHelpFile = Err.HelpFile
    errorHelpContext = Err.HelpContext
    On Error Goto 0
    Call HandleError(errorNumber, errorSource, errorDescription, errorHelpFile, errorHelpContext)
End Sub

Public Sub HandleError(errorNumber As Integer, errorSource As String, errorDescription As String, errorHelpFile As String, errorHelpContext As String)
    Call SendMail(subject, body, mail)
    Err.Raise errorNumber, errorSource, errorDescription, errorHelpFile, errorHelpContext 
End Sub
```

I've not tried it, but it looks like it might work.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work but thanks to you, I could improved the posted code (mentioned you in the first line)

Answer (score 1):

If you use error handling in VBA and want to get the line where the runtime error occured, you need Erl() - and for that you need line numbers, plain and simple.

> Numbering the lines with an addon is no solution since my companies
>   restrictions do not allow addons.

You should really ask them to rethink this policy. Programming VBA without [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) isn't fun, the Global Search and Procedure Callers functions alone are invaluable.

Of course you don't have line numbers on when developing, you add them when giving the code into production.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stop` and `Resume` to return to the line that threw an error however you couldn't use this in production code. What this will do is stop the code running, you can then use F8 to Step Into the next line of code which will return you to the line that raised the error.

```
    Private Sub Foo()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
    a = 7 / 0

    Exit Sub
ErrorHandling:
    errorNumber = Err.Number
    errorSource = Err.Source
    errorDescription = Err.Description
    errorHelpFile = Err.HelpFile
    errorHelpContext = Err.HelpContext

    HandleError errorNumber, errorSource, errorDescription, errorHelpFile, errorHelpContext
    Stop
    Resume
End Sub

Public Sub HandleError(errorNumber As Integer, errorSource As String,  errorDescription As String, errorHelpFile As String, errorHelpContext As String)
    Call SendMail(Subject, body, mail)

End Sub
```

If you need something which will provide error reports from production code I don't believe there is a way to return the Line that threw the error without numbering your lines and using `Erl`. The alternative to this would be to implement your own error raising with meaningful codes which would allow you to identify which part of your code caused an error.

Comment: `stop` and `resume` will only stop in the current line, so it can neither be used to help me.

Comment: No, stop enables to you pause the code at that point. The resume will resume at the line that raised the error ie A = 7 / 0. You can't use this in production code as the resume would cause you to enter an infinite loop assuming the error continued to occur, but it can be useful for debugging.